# List - Filter at beginning

Tags: list, filter

All,

I have a Person list with Status column (Active/Inactive). Is there a way when user clicks on Person list, it just displays Active Person only? Can we make the Filer of Status Column chooses Active at the beginning? 

Thanks.

Comment: You could just make an additional list view where it just displays active persons only.

Comment: Adding to above comment - and you can modify that view to apply filter on Status column and also you can make that view as default view so that whenever you click on person list only Active Person will be displayed.